# What data type does C# return in a SQL CE query (using WebMatrix)?

Tags: c#, sql, types, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I spent some time Googling and some time researching here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/

However, I cannot seem to find a simple answer to this question:

What C# data type is returned to the following `row` variable when I return some data from a database like the line shown below:

```
selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM ContentObjects INNER JOIN TitleObjects ON ContentObjects.ObjectID = TitleObjects.ObjectID WHERE location='home' AND type = 'title' AND TitleObjects.ObjectID = @0";

row = db.QuerySingle(subSelectQueryString, someNumber);
```

I ask because I need to declare `row` at the beginning of the page, before I use it, but it must be initialized and I can't seem to do this without knowing the datatype.

**UPDATE:**

BTW, `var db = Database.Open("tableName")`

Comment: your link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ seems too general for your researching? You might try more specific links.

Comment: @David I really don't know where to look, honestly.

Comment: will http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.querysingle%28v=vs.111%29.aspx be better to you?

Comment: @David Okay, yes, I've seen many pages like this, but how can I tell what the data type is?

Comment: @according to MSDN, this should return an "object", I would then conjecture that this is dependent on your application, otherwise if it can be generic, it won't return an object, since .net is strongly typed and will try to maintain the generic property as it can.

Comment: @David I thought it was object, but when I try to use a returned row, like, `@row.linkText` it thinks I am trying to call a method of object instead of obviously wanting the column `linkText` which is returned from the query. This is the correct syntax for such a thing, but I don't know how to get C# to tell them apart, I guess? I don't know. Will C# error if it runs into another `var` for a certain variable after the first? This is why I need to pre-initialize this variable, but I can't use var without a default value, and if I use `""` it will think it is a string (likewise for other types).

Comment: yes. I think you can try cast it to some strong types, according to your estimate, and check if it is null after the cast. I have no prior knowledge on your "db" object, that is what I can help so far.

Comment: @David BTW, `var db = Database.Open("tableName")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QuerySingle method returns a `dynamic` type (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). The field names from the schema become properties of the dynamic object. The compiler (or in the case of `dynamic`, the runtime binder) will only think you are attempting to call a method if you follow the property with brackets e.g.

```
@row.linktext()
```

Comment: Really? I wasn't using brackets but it seemed to think I was trying to call a method anyway (at least, that's what the error was saying, but we all know how inaccurate the errors can sometimes be). I had to just use `var` within some loop (which I was afraid of doing), but it doesn't seem to error because of it, so I guess I'm okay.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly define your row object, it will base the columns on the SQL Server types.  You will have to know the definition of the ContectObjects table from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a `dynamic` datatype

`dynamic` is a new datatype in C# 4.0. Its simply a datatype that is handled on runtime. dynamic figures out datatypes of an object after compilation e.g

```
selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM ContentObjects INNER JOIN TitleObjects ON ContentObjects.ObjectID = TitleObjects.ObjectID WHERE location='home' AND type = 'title' AND TitleObjects.ObjectID = @0";

row = db.QuerySingle(subSelectQueryString, someNumber);

var the_field_content = row.location;
```

If your query method was `db.Query` , its going to return an `IEnumerable<object>` which gives you the extra advantage of digging deeper using LINQ methods or object methods e.g `row.Length;` or `row.Skip(5).Take(2).Select(row);`

Try declaring the variable row as var, hit a breakpoint on it in visual studio and hover over it. The datatype is going to show up.Its a `dynamic`

Comment: This is incorrect. The QuerySingle method does NOT return an Enumerable.

Comment: Query returns an IEnumerable not QuerySingle. Sorry about that.